# How to reuse website templates (layout/theme) in Python Django?

Tags: python, django, html-templates

I'm new to web-dev, but among those simple apps I wrote in Django, there's a simple *base_generic.html* as the website page template, like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  {% block sidebar %}<!-- insert default navigation text for every page -->{% endblock %}
  {% block content %}<!-- default content text (typically empty) -->{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

inside which we have a few *block*s, so that we could extends from there to add new page content.

This *html* template is really simple and poor-looking, and I need some good-looking page templates, so I wonder

1) could it be possible to download website page templates of, say *WordPress* (they have many beautiful ones), and use in Django?

2) or what's the typical we to resolve my issue in Django world?

Comment: copy and paste source code to your base template and modify according to your needs. Simple.

Comment: @Debendra, that is I was thinking about, will try

Comment: How about creating on your own. ( just an opinion) In my case I have created 4 types of header and footer, 2 types of navbar(a long with height auto and short one) and 2 base template (with mobile responsive) a standard size of 980px and one with 100%. It took me few weeks and I have looked upon wix and wordpress to get to know different types. Trust me I can use those as skeleton to most of my projects and can add block content according to project.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi, I thought about this, but kind of intimidating to me, I'm quite new to web kinda stuff

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the WordPress (or any other) templates consist of several parts. There's an html carcass, CSS styles applied to elements and some JavaScript logic.

To use page templates, you need to find and download the whole pack: the html page itself and CSS and JS it's using and put CSS and JS to static files (see [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/) about serving states files in Django).

Then you just serve your html templates, which include static files from your static folder.

Comment: emm, looks like not so easy, so I need to copy lots of stuff, not just the html, but also the js/css?

Comment: @avocado, if the template you chose uses only external styles and scripts, you don't need to copy anything, but it's rare. Anyway, you need to actually see what files are in the template.